# jquery validation for numeric entry?

Tags: jquery, validation, phone-number

I have the following for Length validation but how would I validate for numeric only?

```
    function cmdvalidate() {
        if (len($('#txtReqAreaCode').val()) < 3) {
            alert("Please check the requester's phone number.  It must be 10 digits.");
            $('#txtReqAreaCode').focus();
            return false;
        } else if (len($('#txtRequestorPhone').val()) < 3) {
            alert("Please check the requester's phone number.  It must be 10 digits.");
            $('#txtRequestorPhone').focus();
            return false;
        } else if (len($('#txtRequestorPhonePt2').val()) < 4) {
            alert("Please check the requester's phone number.  It must be 10 digits.");
            $('#txtRequestorPhonePt2').focus();
            return false;
```

Comment: Please google and read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isnumeric/)

Comment: multiplie and if bigger then 0 its a number

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this (RegExp, parseInt comparison, ...), but as you are using jQuery anyway just use [jQuery's isNumeric](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isnumeric/) function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using a lot of unnecessary duplication in your code.

```
  alert("Please check the requester's phone number.  It must be 10 digits.");
        $('#txtRequestorPhonePt2').focus();
        return false;
```

Is shown three times. Try storing `phone_length` and `phone_string` in variables

```
var phone_length = $('#txtReqAreaCode').text().length + 
$('#txtRequestorPhone').text().length + $('#txtRequestorPhonePt2').text.length()

var phone_string = $('#txtReqAreaCode').val() + $('#txtRequestorPhone`).val() + 
$('txtRequestorPhonePt2').val();
```

Then, your main function should be

```
if (phone_length < 10 && phone_string.search(/\D/) !== -1)  {
    alert("Please check the requester's phone number.  It must be 10 digits.");
    $('#txtRequestorPhonePt2').focus();
    return false;
}
```

JavaScript's `string#search` method searches a string for a particular pattern. In this case, I used the 
`/\D/` regex symbol to find anything that's not a digit.

The search function returns the index of the matched character. If it's not found, it will return `-1`.